# Create parent object in child create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, strong-parameters

There are many related question on SO. I went through all of them but still struggle with my situation.

I have two models `User` and `Booking`

```
#model/user.rb
has_many :bookings

#modle/booking.rb
belongs_to :user
```

I want to create a `booking` and a `user` at the same time. If the user already exist, just add the new booking to the existing user.

My form for creating `booking`:

```
<%= simple_form_for :booking, url: bookings_path, :method => :post, do |f| %>
<%= f.fields_for :user, do |ff| %>
  <%= ff.input_field :first_name %>
  <%= ff.input_field :last_name %>
  <%= ff.input_field :email %>
  <%= ff.input_field :phone %>
<% end %>
...
<% end %>
```

And in the `booking` controller

```
#control/bookings_controller.rb
def create
  @user = User.find_by(:email => booking_params[:user][:email])
  if @user == nil
    @user = User.new(booking_params[:user])
    @user.username = User.autousername(@user)
    @user.password = Devise.firendly_token(8)
  else
    @user.update(booking_params[:user])
  end
  @user.save
  b_params = booking_params
  b_params.delete("user")
  @booking = Booking.new(b_params)
  @booking.user_id = @user.id
  @booking.save
...
end

def booking_params
  params.require(:booking).permit(:status, :house_id, :check_in, :check_out, :adult_guest, :children_guest, :temp_profit,
  :note, :check_in_note, :user => [:first_name, :last_name, :email, :phone])
end
```

I didn't use nested_attributes because I want to generate username and password myself rather than collect them using form.

What I got is `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in BookingsController#create
User(#70121505047640) expected, got ActionController::Parameters(#70121556154400)`

Most SO related problems want to create the child object under parent controller. In my case, it's reversed.

**UPDATE**

After trying every possible way, I found out that the CanCanCan `load_and_authorize_resource` seems to be the trouble maker. If I comment out it in my bookings_controller, everything works fine. Could someone tell me why?

**Solution**

Finally, I found out the reason. I'm using CanCanCan `load_and_authorize_resource` in my `booking_controller`. In order to create nested `user` instance under it, I have to load `user` resources. Just add `load_and_authorize_resource :user` will solve the problem!

Thanks for all the answers. Hope this will help people with the same problem.

Comment: http://blog.pivotal.io/pivotal-labs/labs/form-backing-objects-for-fun-and-profit

Comment: please show full backtrace

Answer (score 0):

This is probably happening when you try to do the `@booking.save`.  Because you have a user param, it will try to use the user= to set it.  In this case, the user= will apply a params object.

Try to delete the user param from the booking_params when you create the booking.

```
b_params.delete(:user)
```

or

```
b_params[:user] = @user
```

Comment: I tried both solutions. Still getting the same error. : (

Comment: I check the trace and there is indeed "user=" record. I think the problem should be what you suggested. But I still get the error even I delete the user part from booking_params.

Comment: You could remove it form the booking_params method and instead get the user from params[:user], then change the form so :user is not a child of :booking.